# futures-rs using Stream combinators on `BoxStream`s

Tags: rust, future

Using the [`futures-rs`](https://docs.rs/futures) library, I've encountered a situation where a stream needs to be mapped through an indeterminate number of other streams before being returned to the user.  Since the exact type of the output stream is unknown at the end of this operation, I've been using a [`BoxStream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.9/futures/stream/type.BoxStream.html) trait object while storing the stream in a struct and when returning it.

Although this approach works fine, it has the unfortunate side effect of causing the inner `Stream` object to be unsized.  This is a problem because *every one* of the [stream combinators](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.9/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) require `Self: Sized` in their signatures meaning that I can't even `wait()` on the returned `BoxStream` in order to convert it into a blocking iterator.

Here's an example of a situation that could lead to this issue:

```
struct Server {
    receiver: Option<Box<Stream<Item = usize, Error = ()> + Send>>,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn new() -> Server {
        let (tx, rx) = channel(0);
        // do things with the tx (subscribe to tcp socket, connect to database, etc.)
        Server { receiver: Some(rx.boxed()) }
    }

    /// Maps the inner `Receiver` through another stream, essentially duplicating it.
    pub fn get_stream(&mut self) -> Result<Box<Stream<Item = usize, Error = ()> + Send>, ()> {
        let (tx, rx) = channel(0);

        let strm = self.receiver.take().unwrap();
        let mut tx_opt = Some(tx);
        let new_strm = strm.map(move |msg| {
            // unfortunate workaround needed since `send()` takes `self`
            let mut tx = tx_opt.take().unwrap();
            tx = tx.send(msg.clone()).wait().unwrap();
            tx_opt = Some(tx);
            msg
        });
        simbroker.receiver = Some(new_strm.boxed());

        Ok(rx.boxed())
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let server = Server::new();

    // possible that this may happen 0..n times
    let rx: BoxStream<usize, ()> = server.get_stream();

    // can't do this since the inner `Stream` trait object isn't `Sized` and `wait()`
    // (along with all other stream combinators) requires that in their signatures.
    for msg in rx.wait() {
        // compiler error here
        // ...
    }
}
```

As shown by the above code, `BoxStream`s are necessary since calling `map()` on a stream changes its type from `Receiver` to `Map` which would make it impossible to store back into the struct.  It's impossible to do pretty much anything with the returned `BoxStream` since it's `?Sized`.  In fact, the *only* function that's available for trait-object `Stream`s is `poll()` which is supposed to never be called outside of a `Task`.

Is there any way that I can avoid this problem without doing something like returning an enum containing any one of the possible varieties of stream that could possibly occur?  Would writing my own struct that implements `Stream` fix the issue somehow?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue (after fixing unrelated issues). There's `impl<S: ?Sized + Stream> Stream for Box<S>` in futures-rs that should make this just work. Make sure your question contains an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the error message you're getting.

Comment: Ohhh; in this particular test I hadn't done `use futures::Stream`; rustc was encountering the unsized error due to that `impl<S: ?Sized + Stream>` living inside the `Stream` module as `wait()` so the compilation errored out before it even noticed `wait()` wasn't in scope.  Thanks so much @FrancisGagné!  If you want to make this into an answer I'll accept it as solved; if not I'll do so myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @FrancisGagné in a comment, `futures-rs` declares `impl<S: ?Sized + Stream> Stream for Box<S>` in the `futures::Stream` module.  In the test in which my code was, I had failed to import `Stream` so that trait wasn't in scope.

The compiler didn't trigger an error for the lack of the `wait()` function because it had the unsized issue first.

This was resolved by adding `use futures::Stream;` to the start of the function.